# Unable to start Tor

Tags: error

Tor said that an update was available, ran that and all seemed ok.
When I click on the icon to run Tor I get: "Unable to start Tor. Failed to get hashed password."

Comment: Almost 100% guaranteed to be caused by your anti-virus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I made a copy of my bookmarkbackups folder, deleted the tor browser folder and did a clean install of tor 7.5 and then it would  start and immediately crash.

I deleted the tor browser folder again and installed Version 7.0.10 and turned off automatic updating.

Win 10x64 pro Version 18299.192